# JQuery scrollTop causes problems in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, scrolltop

I'm hoping some genius can help me debug my JQuery function.  It works fine on Firefox and Safari but on Chrome it fails to completely render the background.  The strange thing is that it fixes itself if I resize my browser window in any way.

The JQuery is also causing the hover properties on the top navigation to break whenever you scroll down on the site.

I am new to the world of coding so I could really use some help. I'm convinced it has something to do with "window.scroll" but I really don't know.

You can visit my site: [Here](http://rbrewer.mydevryportfolio.com/)

I made a JFiddle: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/brewersomething/hY7qu/)

And I've pasted my Javascript/JQuery below:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    flag=true;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        st = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(st>170){
            if(flag);
            $("#flipBox_contain").css("opacity", ".2");
            $("#flipBox_contain").css({"position": "relative"});
        }
        else if(st<170){
            if(flag);
            $("#flipBox_contain").css("opacity", "1");
            $("#flipBox_contain").css("position", "");
        }
        if(st>400){
            if(flag);
            $("#introText").css("opacity", ".2");
            $("#introText").css({"position": "relative"});
        }
        else if(st<400){
            if(flag);
            $("#introText").css("opacity", "1");
            $("#introText").css("position", "");
        }
        if(st>500){
            if(flag);
            $("#psLogo").css("top","0px");
            $("#psLogo").css("opacity","1");
            $("#psBar").css("width","98%");
            $("#psLabel").css("opacity","1");
            $("#psSkill").css("opacity","1");
            setTimeout (function(){
                $("#aiLogo").css("top","0px");
                $("#aiLogo").css("opacity","1");
                $("#aiBar").css("width","93%");
                $("#aiLabel").css("opacity","1");
                $("#aiSkill").css("opacity","1");
            }, 500);
            setTimeout (function(){
                $("#htmlLogo").css("top","0px");
                $("#htmlLogo").css("opacity","1");
                $("#htmlBar").css("width","80%");
                $("#htmlLabel").css("opacity","1");
                $("#htmlSkill").css("opacity","1");
            }, 1000);
            setTimeout (function(){
                $("#cssLogo").css("top","0px");
                $("#cssLogo").css("opacity","1");
                $("#cssBar").css("width","80%");
                $("#cssLabel").css("opacity","1");
                $("#cssSkill").css("opacity","1");
            }, 1500);
            setTimeout (function(){
                $("#javaLogo").css("top","0px");
                $("#javaLogo").css("opacity","1");
                $("#javaBar").css("width","60%");
                $("#javaLabel").css("opacity","1");
                $("#javaSkill").css("opacity","1");
            }, 2000);
            setTimeout (function(){
                $("#phpLogo").css("top","0px");
                $("#phpLogo").css("opacity","1");
                $("#phpBar").css("width","40%");
                $("#phpLabel").css("opacity","1");
                $("#phpSkill").css("opacity","1");
            }, 2500);
            /*setTimeout (function(){$("#psLabel").css("opacity","1")}
            , 1600);
            setTimeout (function(){$("#psSkill").css("opacity","1")}
            , 2100)*/
        }
        else if (st<170){
            if(flag);
            $("#psLogo").css("top","100px");
            $("#psLogo").css("opacity","0");
            $("#psBar").css("width","0");
            $("#psLabel").css("opacity","0");
            $("#psSkill").css("opacity","0");
            setTimeout (function(){
                $("#aiLogo").css("top","100px");
                $("#aiLogo").css("opacity","0");
                $("#aiBar").css("width","0");
                $("#aiLabel").css("opacity","0");
                $("#aiSkill").css("opacity","0");
            }, 500);
            setTimeout (function(){
                $("#htmlLogo").css("top","100px");
                $("#htmlLogo").css("opacity","0");
                $("#htmlBar").css("width","0");
                $("#htmlLabel").css("opacity","0");
                $("#htmlSkill").css("opacity","0");
            }, 1000);
            setTimeout (function(){
                $("#cssLogo").css("top","100px");
                $("#cssLogo").css("opacity","0");
                $("#cssBar").css("width","0");
                $("#cssLabel").css("opacity","0");
                $("#cssSkill").css("opacity","0");
            }, 1500);
            setTimeout (function(){
                $("#javaLogo").css("top","100px");
                $("#javaLogo").css("opacity","0");
                $("#javaBar").css("width","0");
                $("#javaLabel").css("opacity","0");
                $("#javaSkill").css("opacity","0");
            }, 2000);
            setTimeout (function(){
                $("#phpLogo").css("top","100px");
                $("#phpLogo").css("opacity","0");
                $("#phpBar").css("width","0");
                $("#phpLabel").css("opacity","0");
                $("#phpSkill").css("opacity","0");
            }, 2500);
        }//--closes else if
        else{flag=false;}
    }); //--closes window.scroll function
}); //--closes document ready function
```

Comment: Please fix the links to your site and jsfiddle.

Comment: It looks like you're just not closing your functions right, this probably screws up your code. At some conditions you have no opening bracket `{`, followed with `else if {` without closing bracket `}`.

Comment: What is `if(flag);` meant to do? Rather be explicit with brackets: `if(flag){...}` if you are just starting out.

Comment: FYI, `$("document")` returns jq empty object, `document` is an object, you need to use `$(document)`. That's said, pseudo ready handler works even on empty object due to promise used internally by jQuery. Be aware, that's not related to your issue here

Comment: All this timeouts inside scroll event is wrong way to do anything, without clearing them. Anyway unfortunately, it's quite hard to figure out what behaviour you are looking for here

Comment: @DaanHeskes if you have a moment I'm not seeing any missing braces. Do you see any in particular?  If you have time to point them out I would be grateful.

Comment: @acarlon I got the basic idea for the function off a StackOverflow post but I think the function might work without the flags.

Comment: @RyanBrewer I thought that you missed some curly brackets but that's because your formatting was kind of messy, now you've changed it I see that I wasn't right.

Comment: @A.Wolff I want the site to function exactly as it does in Firefox but Chrome is having trouble with something in my code.  Maybe it is the timeouts. I will look into that. I replaced `$("document")` with `$(document)` which, strangely enough, actually improved the performance in Chrome a little.

Comment: A few things, What behavior are you exactly looking for? In your question you pointed out the background is not rendered in chrome, which background are you exactly referring to ? the flip-box background ? The only difference I found in the `firefox` and `chrome` was the transparency level of the flip boxes.

Comment: Update: It definitely has something to do with how Chrome is rendering my background.  If I change to a color background from a background image is behaves very strange.  Can someone please shed some light on this for me?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Amyth When I open it Chrome there was a large white box in the middle of the page when the entire background (for the whole window) should be a textured dark blue. But if I resize my window or even scroll a little it fixes itself.  It is very random. Here is the actual image I am using for the background: [link](http://rbrewer.mydevryportfolio.com/images/bg-body.jpg). It sounds like you are getting a different behavior though which is very odd and somewhat troubling.

Comment: @RyanBrewer I actually do get to see the background image both in `chrome` as well as in `Firefox`.

Comment: Here are the screenshots, for chrome: http://s7.postimg.org/qkwm7is7f/rmb_chrome.png and for firefox:http://s23.postimg.org/bu4huycij/rmb_ff.png

Comment: @Amyth thanks for the screenshots.  That is really strange because I have no issue with the backface visibility of the flipboxes when I view them in my Chrome browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is finally solved!  After some considerable 'process-of-elimination' troubleshooting it came down to a simple misuse of the z-index property.  I edited all the divs with z-index so the the values were consistent and none of them were too high (eg: 200) or too low (eg: -99), instead making them all 0, 1 or 2.  That solved Chromes repainting issues.  Hopefully this helps someone else out there.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the negative z-index value you have on `.wrapper`. This is not a valid value.

See this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) for more.

Comment: Thanks Mini.  I know that z-index technically isn't allowed without a position property to accompany it but to get everything to work I had to add z-index to certain elements.  I removed it from `.wrapper` though and everything still works.  The problem is the flipboxes don't flip if there is any positioning involved with any parent element to the flipboxes. That is why I had to add it and remove it on scroll events with the JQuery. Everything validated through WC3 though so I'm not sure what it going on.